# onesignal API, Postman: app_id cannot be found

Tags: json, rest, postman, onesignal

While trying to follow the onesignal documentation to use postman to send a POST request to onesignal to send a notification, I get the following error when trying to send:
`"app_id not found. You may be missing a Content-Type: application/json header."`

I do have the correct content-type header:
[image: Image of my request headers with the API key removed for obvious reasons]

Additionally, I believe my JSON is syntactically correct:

```
{
    "included_segments": [
        "Subscribed Users"
    ],
    "App_id": "{Removed for obvious reasons}",
    "contents": {
        "en": "This is a message, sent from postman using the onesignal API"
    },
    "headings": {
        "en": "This is a heading"
    },
    "subtitle": {
        "en": "This is a subtitle, it should only appear on iOS devices"
    },
    "ios_badgeType": "SetTo",
    "ios_badgeCount": 1,
    "priority": 10
}
```

Not sure where to go from here.

Documentation here: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/using-postman

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try removing double quotes from the body and make sure you have selected json from the body drop down . Also try removing content type as postman adds it Automatically

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Wouldn't removing the double quotes make the JSON invalid? Postman yelled at me when I replaced the double quotes with single quotes. I do have JSON selected in the body dropdown, and I tried removing the content-type header and it still gave me the same error.

Comment: Single quotes is not valid json character , is app Id a number ?

Comment: Of it's a number then you don't need the quotes

Comment: The app id is a string, so for that reason it needs the double quotes.

Comment: in the documentation app id doesn't have doube quotes so it should be a number not string

Comment: Also try removing custom header content-type postman adds it autoamtticallly

Comment: @PDHide In looking into the documentation for all of the options you can use in the JSON, the app_id is a string, https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference/create-notification. Removing the custom header content-type resulted in the same error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved this issue and am adding my solution for people in the future.
In the json body of my message, I had "App_id" and it wanted "app_id". Changing the case of the a made it work.